# Key Vault referenced application settings in Logic apps are not getting refreshed

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault

I have a Key vault reference app setting in Logic app. When networking rules implemented on the key vault, Key vault reference app setting showed an error

**Error Details:
Key Vault reference was not able to be resolved because site was denied access to Key Vault reference's vault.**

But ones we revert the networking rules in KV to allow traffic from all networks, still the logic app application settings shows same error. I did restarted logic app couple of times, but no luck.

Could you help on fixing the app settings issue in logic apps.

Comment: Did you face same error, before implementing networking rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible options to resolve the mentioned issue.

1. Creating Access Policy for Logic app in Key vault.
2. Removing App setting in logic app and adding again Key vault App setting in logic app.

I have reproduced issue from my side. Removing app setting in logic app and adding it again resolved my issue. Below are steps I followed,

- Created a key vault and added a secret.
- Created a standard logic app and enabled system managed identity.
  [image]
- Added access policy in key vault for logic app.
  [image]
- Added key vault reference in logic app configuration.
- Implemented network rules on key vault then getting below error,
  **Key Vault reference was not able to be resolved because site was denied access to Key Vault reference's vault.**
  [image]
- Removed key vault secret setting from logic app configuration and added again.
- Issue got resolved as shown below,

[image]

[image]
Reference [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105357/how-to-resolve-keyvault-references-to-secrets-via-application-settings-in-functi)
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036960/key-vault-reference-error-in-azure-web-app-configuration-setting)